# Does threading.Condition maintain a collection of Thread objects?

Tags: python, multithreading

Trying to wrap my wits around how `threading` works. The high-level language in the docs and source code is helpful up to a degree but still leaves me scratching my head. What exactly, in terms of data structures, is the relationship between `Thread` and `Condition` objects? What does it mean when a thread "releases" a lock? That the `Condition` object dequeues its reference to the thread? Is there a lower-level description of these interactions, preferably in Python terms, to be found on the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Condition` maintains a list (actually a `collections.deque`) of what are notionally threads, waiting on the condition. It actually stores locks that the waiting threads are blocked on, but thinking of it storing the threads is a conceptual shortcut if you don't care too much about the implementation. The list is initially empty, but any time a thread calls the `Condition`'s `wait` method, it will create a new lock and add it to the list before blocking on the lock (conceptually, this adds the thread to the list, and suspends it). Locks are removed from the list after another thread calls `notify` or `notify_all`, which unlocks one or more of the lock objects in the list, waking up the corresponding threads.

Releasing a lock means unlocking it. It's a basic operation on a `Lock` object (the reverse of `acquire`, which locks the `Lock`). A lock is "held" in between an `acquire` and a `release`, and only one thread can hold a `Lock` at a given time (other threads will either block in `acquire`, or the operation will fail, perhaps after a timeout). You can use the context manager protocol to call `acquire` and `release` for you in simple cases:

```
with some_lock:  # this acquires some_lock, blocking until it's available
    do_stuff()  # some_lock is held while this runs

# some_lock will be released automatically when the with block ends
```

Each `Condition` object is associated with a `Lock`, either a pre-existing one that you pass to its constructor, or one it creates internally for you (if you don't pass anything). The main `Condition` operations (`wait` and `notify`, and their variants) require that you already hold the associated lock before you call them. You can do the lock operations directly on the `Condition` object itself, since it proxies the `Lock`'s `acquire` and `release` methods (and the equivalent context manager methods).

The `Condition` class is written in pure Python, so if you want to know how it works on a low level, there's probably no better source of information than [the source code itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1672c2fbae6128ee4717e08c4e65a0ab99a02a02/Lib/threading.py#L203)!

It might also be useful to see how a `Condition` is used to synchronize multithreaded access to an object. A good example of that is [the `queue` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/queue.py) in the standard library, where each `Queue` uses three `Condition`s (`not_full`, `not_empty` and `all_tasks_done`) to efficiently manage threads that are trying to access or modify its data.

Comment: I thank you for trying to explain. But however intuitively correct "hold a lock" may be, it doesn't help me grasp what's actually happening with the data structures. Nice link into the source.

Comment: So does the Lock instance contain a queue of Thread instances? I can't seem to find the source for `RLock`.

Comment: Python's `Thread` and `Lock` types are wrappers around primitives that are ultimately provided by the system threading libraries. Locks are very basic pieces of any multi-threaded code, but there are many ways to implement them (so the answer to "how does a lock work at a low level" may have many answers, depending on your OS, hardware, and the libraries a given program is using). One reason to use higher-level tools (like `queue`s) is that you don't need to care about the low level details, which may vary from system to system.

Comment: I finally looked over the `queue` module and found it quite helpful.